# remove an event using removeEventListener before adding an event using addEventListener is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a general function that allows to subscribe to any event. I want make sure that is only made one subscription for each event and element. So, before I add a new event listener, I remove the previous one.

The problem is, the way that I'm making it the previous event is not being remove and I don't know why.

Follows a working example:

```js
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
  let eventListenerHandler = (event) => {
    var t = event.target;
      while (t && t !== this) {
          if (t.matches && t.matches(sel)) {
              handler.call(t, event);
          }
          t = t.parentNode;
      }
  }
  el.removeEventListener(evt, eventListenerHandler, evt === "focus" ? true : false);
  el.addEventListener(evt, eventListenerHandler, evt === "focus" ? true : false);
}
let consoleLog = () => console.log("WAS FOCUS");
delegate(document, "focus", "input", consoleLog);
delegate(document, "focus", "input", consoleLog);
```

```html
<input/>
<input/>
```

As you can see in the example, each time an input is selected, is printing 2 times the message "WAS FOCUS" and want I want is to make sure that only one is printed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The two `eventListenerHandler`s across calls are two different function objects. You need to use the same one, or hold on separately to the existing one if the functions might be different.

Comment: @Ry- With my changed the issue remains. Can you tell me if the change that I made was what you suggested to do?

Comment: Sorry, I kind of glossed over the inner function declaration for a moment. Comment edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One relatively simple way to achieve what Ry suggested in comments, would be to store the handler function on the element itself - I've gone for an object here, so that handlers for different event types can be stored under the event name. (You only ever want to have one handler for one event type per element, right?)

And then if such a stored handler already exists, it is simply removed *before* it is overwritten with the new one.

Now storing such data directly "on" a DOM element is not considered good practice; not least because of possible collision with future specified properties of the same name. But in this case it is a very easy way to solve this; of course you could store the handler functions somewhere else, but you would still have to keep the reference to the DOM element around anyway, because you need to be able to differentiate between the handlers assigned to different elements as well.

```js
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
  el.eventListenerHandler = el.eventListenerHandler || {};
  if(el.eventListenerHandler[evt]) {
    el.removeEventListener(evt, el.eventListenerHandler[evt], evt === "focus" ? true : false);
  }
  el.eventListenerHandler[evt] = (event) => {
    var t = event.target;
      while (t && t !== this) {
          if (t.matches && t.matches(sel)) {
              handler.call(t, event);
          }
          t = t.parentNode;
      }
  }
  el.addEventListener(evt, el.eventListenerHandler[evt], evt === "focus" ? true : false);
}
let consoleLog = () => console.log("WAS FOCUS");
delegate(document, "focus", "input", consoleLog);
delegate(document, "focus", "input", consoleLog);
```

```html
<input/>
<input/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For `removeEventListener(event,functionName)` you have to provide same function to be removed which has been added previously.

Now here, each `delegate(document, "focus", "input", consoleLog);` create function `eventListenerHandler` on it's own scope and add it to addEventListener.

Basically two delegate() call create two different function `eventListenerHandler` with same functionality.

Now if we can save the previously added `eventListenerHandler` to a variable and use it in `removeEventListener` later then it will work.

Here is the example.

```js
var temp = function(){};
    function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
      let eventListenerHandler = (event) => {
        var t = event.target;
          while (t && t !== this) {
              if (t.matches && t.matches(sel)) {
                  handler.call(t, event);
              }
              t = t.parentNode;
          }
      }
      el.removeEventListener(evt, temp, evt === "focus" ? true : false);
      el.addEventListener(evt, eventListenerHandler, evt === "focus" ? true : false);
      temp = eventListenerHandler ;
    }
    let consoleLog = () => console.log("WAS FOCUS");
    delegate(document, "focus", "input", consoleLog,false);
    delegate(document, "focus", "input", consoleLog,false);
```

```html
<input>
<input>
```

For better understanding you can refer to javascript [**Closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) concept.

For your solution you have to save each function added as eventListener against it's event & element and remove that function in later call on that element with same event.